# How to align view to right of another without squashing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Surely this is a frequent use-case but I can't seem to resolve it with a LinearLayout (or RelativeLayout) but maybe I'm missing something.

Best explained with an image:

[image]

I have a basic textview chatbubble with another textview aligned to the right (the timestamp for the message).

Both are `wrap_content` (but the timestamp could be set to like precisely 40dp but doesn't seem to matter).

Now in first (top) message it is short so you can see the view to the right.

But in the second the string is long so the `wrap_content` has taken up the whole width of the phone, pushing the timestamp textview out of the screen (horizontal linearlayout, but relativelative `toRightOf` does the same)

So how can I place a timestamp aligned right of another view, but the timestamp will be guaranteed size (not wrap/squash -the message bubble string wraps instead)

(I realise I *could* use a RTL layout, but I have messages from both sides so I would need LTR in other cases + min sdk api 17 is too high for a layout hack).

Comment: Try to set the layout_width of the first TextView to "0dp" and layout_weight to "1". The second TextView's width should remain wrap_content.

Comment: Boom, I think you got it in one! Thanks. (But only when the parent of these two is wrap_content)

Comment: Great, I'll submit this as an answer so that you can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `LinearLayout` widget with horizontal `orientation` and one of its children wants to take all the available horizontal space then you should use layout weight.

For the first `TextView` set:

```
layout_width="0dp"
layout_weight="1"
```

For the second `TextView`:

```
layout_width="wrap_content"
```

In this case you say that second `TextView` will take as much horizontal space as needed and the first `TextView` will take the rest. "0dp" is just an optimization to prevent extra layout measure calls.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

   <!-- the text -->
   <TextView
           android:width="0dp"
           android:height="wrap_content"
           android:weight="1"/>
<!-- the time -->
   <TextView
           android:width="match_parent"
           android:height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or this:

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:width="match_parent"
       android:height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <!-- the text -->
       <TextView
               android:width="match_parent"
               android:height="wrap_content"
               android:maxWidth="300dp"/> <!-- can be a different dimention -->
    <!-- the time -->
       <TextView
               android:width="match_parent"
               android:height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not going to work.. #1 will never display the first TextView because its height is 0dp. The weight will not affect height because layout orientation is horizontal. #2 will work but the solution is just unacceptable, you will have to hardcode the maxWidth for all possible phone / tablet orientations. This is not a good way to go.

Comment: I edited the first answer, all you have to do is put 0dp in the width... The second answer is an option If you want the textview to not be bigger than a fixed size...